# sum of columns that are already sum in sql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp_no, sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='WO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  WO,
    sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='WP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  WP, 
sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='HL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  HL, 
sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  A,**sum(WO+WP+HL+A)** 
from TRN_ATTN072013 WHERE CONVERT(varchar,Tdate,112)>'20130712' and CONVERT(varchar,Tdate,112)<'20130717' 
group by emp_no
ORDER BY emp_no
```

i want to sum up this columns WO,WP,HL,A how do i sum these columns

Comment: Which RDBMS is it? MySQL or SQL SERVER or RDBMS agnostic?

Answer (score 6):

If this is `SQL server` then you can use `CTE`

```
with tablesum as
(
  SELECT DISTINCT emp_no, sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='WO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  WO,
                          sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='WP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  WP,
                          sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='HL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  HL,
                          sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  A
  from TRN_ATTN072013 
  WHERE CONVERT(varchar,Tdate,112) > '20130712' and CONVERT(varchar,Tdate,112) < '20130717'
  group by emp_no      
)

select t.*, t.WO + t.WP + t.HL + t.A
from tablesum t
order by t.emp_no
```

Comment: This is all kinds of wrong. Order by in a CTE? SUM without group by?

Comment: Yes, sorry was a bit hasty.

Comment: Why are you grouping by what you are aggregating? Why not just change that bottom part to something like select t.*, t.WO + t.WP + t.HL + t.A
from tablesum t
order by t.emp_no

Comment: OK, that looks better. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

in mysql ;)

```
SELECT emp_no, wo+wp+hl+A FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT emp_no, sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='WO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  WO,
sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='WP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  WP, 
sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='HL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  HL, 
sum(CASE WHEN isnull(PresAbs,0)='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  A,**sum(WO+WP+HL+A)** 
from TRN_ATTN072013 WHERE CONVERT(varchar,Tdate,112)>'20130712' and   CONVERT(varchar,Tdate,112)<'20130717' 
group by emp_no
ORDER BY emp_no) AS SUB_Q;
```